# Mac OS Sierra 10.12 autofs mounts only the first specified NFS volume

Tags: osx, nfs, autofs

I am having an issue with the Mac OS Sierra. I have added a NFS config in a auto_nfs for 2 NFS shares and the autofs picks only the first one.

Here's my auto_master:

```
#
# Automounter master map
#
+auto_master        # Use directory service
/net            -hosts      -nobrowse,hidefromfinder,nosuid
/home           auto_home   -nobrowse,hidefromfinder
/Network/Servers    -fstab
/-              auto_nfs    -nosuid
/-          -static
```

Here's my auto_nfs:

```
/build/mount1       -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,ro,tcp,nfc nfs://<some hostname>:/mount1 
/build/mount2       -fstype=nfs,noowners,nolockd,noresvport,hard,bg,intr,ro,tcp,nfc nfs://<some hostname>:/mount2
```

When I restart the autofs service with this **sudo automount -cv** I get the following message:

```
automount: /net updated
automount: /home updated
automount: /build/mount1 updated
automount: no unmounts
```

and the mount2 is not mounted under my build directory. If I change the order in auto_nfs to be mount2 followed by mount1, then I get only mount2 mounted.

If I put the

```
/-              auto_nfs    -nosuid
```

line at the end of the auto_mount then nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After traying everything I was able to resolve my issue. I gave my **auto_nfs** config to a colleague of mine. In order to make the thing simpler I send the config over Skype. When he applied it everything worked fine for him. Having this in mind I re-created my **auto_nfs** file using the content that I just send over Skype, then I called

> sudo automount -cv

again and everything worked. It seems that there was some kind of issue with the encoding and/or spaces in the original file.